# No "driver" tab in my hard drive's properties

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

In order to disable a hard drive without physically unplugging it, [one can go](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-a-hdd-without-unplugging-it/013004db-1ccf-4511-bef6-35d1ebcc6233) to the "driver" tab in the hard drive properties and click "disable device" button.

Except my hard drive has no such tab. Why not and how to fix that?

EDIT: I think it's a 2.5-inch hard drive with a SATA connector.

The hard drive in question is `SEAGATE F:`

Screenshots of disk management and device manager:

### Disk management

[image: disk management]

### Device manager

### [image: device manager]

---

Comment: Is this a USB Drive?  Then there is likely not a tab in Device / Disk Manager

Comment: Which disk is this and how is it connected?

Comment: On my windows 10 box, the property tab is there for USB, SSD, and HDD (I just checked).  From explorer, right click your drive -> properties -> Hardware tab.  Is your drive listed?  If you go to properties from there, is it the same as the disk manager?

Comment: Nope, not listed there. But I do see it in disk manager.

Comment: Please add screen shots of the part of the device manager that will show "Disk drives" expanded and Disk Management (the whole thing).  That would be very helpful.  Oh, I too am using a 2.5 inch drive with a sata connector to usb but the controller can be a factor (mine is SABRENT)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas OK, just edited my question accordingly

Comment: @drake035 In what way do you want it disabled? You can set it to "Offline" in disk management if that's sufficient for your needs. (Right-click in the box where you can see "Online" and choose "Offline".)

Comment: Great edit!  I don't see any USB2SATA adapters unless you are talking about one of the WD my passport drives.  I still don't see why you are having problems but don't doubt you at all.  If it is one of the WD drives, they notoriously power down (stop spinning) and make the system lag when spinning back up.  Is this what you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you double click it in device manager, can you disable it from there?  This is all very strange indeed unless what @Irwene below suggests in comments that it might be somehow tied to being an OS drive.

Comment: "SEAGATE" is a **volume label** and has no relationship with the actual plug-n-play drive name shown in Device Manager.

Comment: So I cannot disable the drive from disk management (contrary to instructions in the article I linked). But I can do it from device manager. Thanks @SeñorCMasMas.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the device manager?

(Right click on the start menu logo => Device Manager)

Then search the "Disk Drive" category.

You *should* find your drive under this category, you can then right-click => disable

*Note* : I just tested this on an USB Drive, should work the same on an internal one (I get the option on other drives (internal SSDs))

---

Edit:

The drive you want to "disable" is a partition on a disk that also have a system partition which is probably why you don't see the disable button you're expecting to.

Alternatively, if it's just about hiding the partitions, you could just remove the drive letters in the disk manager.

Comment: The dialog produced by disk manager and the one you describe are the same dialog.  OP has something fishy going on.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The only instance where I've seen the disable device be disable is on my OS drive, if he's trying to cut access to one of the parition on his main drive that  could explain the issue

Comment: Good guess! :) We will see.  I will +1 you if this shows as true and you edit your answer to include it after we figure this out.

Comment: He's talking about missing TAB. It seems that's not what you guys are talking about.

Comment: Your comment should be in your answer, and as promised.. +1.

Comment: Adding it then :)

Answer (score 0):

Your disk contains a System Reserved partition, which Disk Management identifies as "active". That means it likely contains boot files for your Windows installation. As such, it can not be disabled.

Comment: While this may be true, it seems to be on my system, it still shows the TAB.